# Targeting a specific LI CSS

Tags: css

I am new to css but learning. I am trying to figure out how to setup a specific class that I can target only certain `<li>` fields. Here is what I tried but it's not working could you please provide any suggestions to help me?

I am trying to create a menu bar for my site and I have css that targets `<li>` from the parent menu. But I also want to be able to create a specific css for certain `<li>` to call for example like this:

```
<li class="nodropdown">bla... bla...</>
```

Here is what I tried to do but I don't know how to create the class properly. I know it's really bad but I am new and trying. Thanks!!

```
#menu li #nodropdown {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li:hover #nodropdown {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
}

#menu li a #nodropdown {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu li:hover a #nodropdown {
    color:#161616;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

classes always start with a `.`, only IDs start with '#'.

So it's: `#menu li.nodropdown`

Note that the is no space between li and . because the class is directly on the li.

Edit: I'd recommend reading through this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: @LeJared thank you so using a . is a class and # is an ID. Now how do I turn these into a classes like this? `#menu li.nodropdown` & `#menu li:hover.nodropdown` & `#menu li a.nodropdown` & `#menu li:hover a.nodropdown` Is this correct? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not teach you the very basics of CSS here. You really should have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp which is a rather complete and easy to understand tutorial for CSS beginners.

Comment: @LeJared: Nobody should look at any w3schools page ever. *Especially* not someone who's still learning things and won't notice that what he reads might be wrong or bad. http://w3fools.com

Comment: Well, make a suggestion for a better site to learn CSS for beginners instead of just complaining.

Comment: @LeJared Although W3Schools is in my opinion still extremely helpful, you should be aware of http://w3fools.com/ and realize that W3Schools.com has a lot of issues and avoid recommending them anymore. With that in mind, you should amend your answer and recommend another resource(s). Here are two from me: [Learn CSS with the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css) and NetTuts' [30 Days to Learn HTML & CSS](http://learncss.tutsplus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is stating the obvious but your specifying a class in your HTML and an ID in your CSS (using the #)